# limit involving trig

Tags: calculus

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my solution to the following, posted below [image: problem]

Suppose, without loss of generality that the circle has radius $1$. Then $\theta = s$. From the law of cosines, we have $d=2+2\cos(\theta)$. From this we get that 
$$\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\frac{s}{d}=\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\theta}{2-2\cos(\theta)}=\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2\sin(\theta)}=\infty.
$$

However, I am told that the answer is $1$. What is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: $d=2+2\cos\theta$ is certainly wrong, since that predicts $d=4$ when $\theta = 0$.  From the picture, $d=0$ when $\theta =0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it $$d^2=1+1-2\cos(\theta)$$?
and use that
$$\cos(\theta)=1-2\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

We have isosceles triangle with legs equal to $1$ and vertex angle equal to $\theta$. Thus, $$d=2 \cdot  \sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$$

Answer (score 0):

If you devide the triangle you find that :

$$d=2 \cdot  \sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$$
$$s=\theta$$

thus

$$\frac{s}{d}=\frac{\theta}{2 \cdot  \sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}$$
$$\frac{s}{d} =\frac{\frac{\theta}{2}}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}$$

finally

$$\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\frac{s}{d}=\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{\theta}{2}}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}=1$$